# uitextfield how to parse the NSString

Tags: ios, uitextfield, nsregularexpression

I am new to iOS.
I have a UITextField where I am adding values like: 1234, 54678, 8976

In the method shouldChangeCharactersInRage i want to take everytime the nsstring after , .
Meaning if i am adding : 1234 in my NSString I want to have 1234
If I have 1234, 5 in my NSStringg i will only have 5

Here is the code I have so far:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string { 

    NSString *getNo=[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\ .*?," options:0 error:NULL];
    NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:getNo options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [getNo length])];
    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [matches lastObject];
    if (match!=nil){
        getNo=@"";
    }
```

The problem in this case is the fact that IN THE FOLLOWING CASE: 1234, 65 instead of having 65 in my getNo, I will have an empty object.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {    
    NSString *textFieldString=[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSArray *subStrings = [textFieldString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSString *lastNumberString = [subStrings lastObject];

    NSString *trimmedString = [lastNumberString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                              [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    return YES;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. How to eliminate the space from the begining or the end of am object in the NSArray?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSArray *subStrings = [textFieldTextString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; //this will returns array of strings separated by ,

double answer = [[subStrings lastObject] doubleValue];//get last value and type cast it
```